# pass thermocouple K type through d-sub and circuit box - what might be error?

Tags: connector, thermocouple

What might be temp error if I'll pass my TC through simple d-sub (green & pink) and from my circuit box (blue) to destination device (yellow) I want to use copper wire, wire lenght between them will be about 1-1,5m, both of them will be same environment.
I alredy have special TC connector (orange), they are expensive hovever it's in variable environment and 2-3m form my curcuit box (blue).

I want to do it because it will simplify my harness but I'm not sure is it worth. I know there are also special thermocuple pins for d-sub but they are so expensive.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Draw your thermocouple connection from the hot-sensing thermocouple junction, all the way to the reference junction at the pins on the sensing IC, showing the material for each wire, and the thermal environment for each junction.

Each time you change material, you will pick up a thermocouple voltage for those two materials at that junction temperature.

This means that if you connect from TCwire through a small non-TC connector and back to TCwire, and the connector is small enough that it's at a more or less uniform temperature throughout, the two TC voltages will essentially cancel out with little error.

If on the other hand you go TCwire to copper, have a long non-TC lead, then back to TCwire, your error can could as big, or bigger than (depending on the thermocouple constant of copper to TCwire), the temperature difference between the two transitions.

If you go to copper wires at your d-sub, and stay in copper all the way to your IC pins, your effective reference junction is your d-sub. The error will be the difference in temperature between your d-sub, and the point at which the IC senses the local temperature. Depending on where these are located, local heat production could mean tens of degrees C difference between them. You could go some way to mitigating this error by putting a thermistor in the d-sub to monitor its local temperature. As most TC ICs can read out their local assumed reference junction temperature, this would allow you to correct for most of the error. Whether this increase in complexity and decrease in accuracy is worth the saving in connector cost is up to you.

Comment: The green lines are my TC wires, it passes through TC connectors (orange) and then through firewall via grommet (black thick line). Yellow and blue device will be tha same area. Panel where is mounted yellow device need to be detachable (pink connector - its same connector as above one)

Comment: Yes, I see your diagram. It makes approximately zero sense. Read my first paragraph. It does really need that level of detail. I can't help you further until you do.

Comment: "my circuit box" do not measure anything, it only passes through signals, "uC" device is the measurement place.

Comment: Most of this problem will be mitigated if the OP can use thermocouple wire for all wiring between the connectors, won't it? Copper connectors joining thermocouple wire should only introduce an error if there's a temperature gradient across the connector itself.

Comment: @nekomatic That's what the third paragraph of my answer says. However, it's not clear from the OP's diagram what materials are used where. There's going to be a temptation to use copper between connectors, because some (most) types of TC wire are a pig to solder. I use Alusol (will solder aluminium!) multicore to solder K-type wires for instance, ordinary multicore won't cut it.

Comment: Ah yes, so it does :-o

Comment: @Dobijasek from your more detailed diagram, P11 has become your reference junction, referred to in my last paragraph. Where is the IC that measures the reference junction temperature, surely your uC does not have a thermocouple interface? If it does, then it knows about the temperature of its pins. Any difference in temperature between P11 and the IC pins will add to the reported temperature and be an error.

Comment: uC is 3rd party device and I do not have any internal schematics. I normal case TC should go directly to the P13 however for better harness managments and other demands I want to pass is through "my circuit box" and P9/J9 connector, alternatively I can skip "my circuit box" and connect TC wires to P9/J9. Also as I understend then if I connect TC to P9 and use TC wire beetween P13 and J9 then error should be minimal as long as there is no gradient on P9/J9 connection?

Comment: if the uC is what does the temperature measurement, then what is its interface to the outside world? Does it have plain screw terminals? Does it have TC material screw terminals? Does it have any documentation about how it should be connected?

Answer (score 0):

Each connection of two different metals is a thermocouple, but if you always swap the same materials like copper->tin->copper->... on both wires and (only then) if both conntacts are on the same temperature, then all these voltages from these thermocouples are cancelling each other.

Now what remains is your main thermocouple made of two different metals that get connected to the copper wires. In fact you should use the same two materials prior to be connected to copper. So you now get a voltage which is proportional to T_tip-T_connector. You may need an RTD sensor on the connector to sense the connector temperature to be added for final result.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4DNrT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

See this terminal, it's made from the same material as connected thermocouple, then a PT100 sensor is measuring the cold junction temperature.

[image]